# Vector field from Lamination.

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology

Let $S$ be a smooth closed (i.e. compact without boundary) surface. A **geodesic lamination** on $S$ is a nonempty closed subset of $S$ which is a disjoint union of geodesics. Suppose $\alpha$ is a geodesic lamination on $S$ such that for every $p\in S$ there is a geodesic of $\alpha$ containing $p$.

**Can we construct a smooth vector field in $S$ using $\alpha$?**

I was trying to use the tangents of the geodesics but I am not sure how to give the orientation on them.

P.S.: If necessary assume that $S$ is a hyperbolic surface.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not just choose a direction for each geodesic component of the lamination?

Comment: @Neal lamination does not come with a natural orientation of the geodesics.So if I choose arbitrary direction for each geodesic then I am not sure whether It will remain continuous or not. For example if I consider $S^2$ and consider the lamination by horizontal circles then to get a continuous vector field all of them should have a particular orientation.

Comment: I think you need to be more precise about what you're looking for - the zero vector field satisfies your requirements in a trivial way. If you're looking for a non-vanishing vector field then the answer is of course no in general; see e.g. the Hairy Ball theorem. I believe the answer is yes locally - for any point you can find a smooth vector field tangent to the foliation in a neighbourhood.

Comment: @Anthony I want a non-trivial global vector field. Not necessarily non-vanishing.

Comment: Take a local solution and multiply it by a bump function with support in the neighbourhood of definition - is that a "non-trivial global vector field"? Perhaps you're looking for a global vector field with a finite number of zeroes?

Comment: Your problem is essentially whether or not the rank-1 distribution generated by the tangent vectors is spanned by a smooth vector field - the terminology of distributions and foliations is a lot more widespread than that of laminations so you may find something searching the web with those terms.

Comment: Are you sure such a lamination exists? $\alpha$ would have to be the whole surface.

Comment: @Steve Good point. I don't have any example. I don't know.

Comment: @SteveD: Oh right, there's an issue - global 1-dimensional foliations only exist when the Euler characteristic is zero, so hyperbolic surfaces certainly don't have global laminations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just ran across this old problem and thought it would be good to give a definitive answer.

As the comments suggest the problem doesn't quite make sense, but there is one way for it to make sense:

> Does there exist a global vector field which is nowhere zero on the lamination and tangent to the lamination?

The answer is no. In fact, a positive answer to the previous question would imply a positive answer to the next question:

> Does there exist a vector field defined only on the lamination which is nowhere zero and is tangent to the lamination?

The answer to this question is also no.

To see why, the question can be reformulated as an orientation problem. Given a geodesic lamination $\Lambda$ in a hyperbolic surface $S$, define its tangent bundle $T\Lambda$ to be the subset of $TS$ consisting of all $(p,v)$, $v \in T_p S$ such that $p \in \Lambda$ and $v$ is tangent to $\Lambda$. This is a 1-dimensional vector bundle over $\Lambda$. Mimicking the usual definition of orientability of a bundle, we define $\Lambda$ to be orientable if $T\Lambda$ is orientable, meaning that $T\Lambda$ has a continuous choice of orientation; and since this is a 1-dimensional vector bundle it is equivalent to the second question above.

To get a counterexample, one uses a method pioneered by Nielsen and developed further, in a constructive manner, by Thurston. Thurston constructed examples $\Lambda \subset S$ where $S$ is a compact hyperbolic surface, such that if one lifts $\Lambda$ under the universal covering map $\mathbb H^2 \to S$, obtaining a geodesic lamination $\tilde\Lambda \subset \mathbb H^2$, there exists a triple of points $p,q,r \in \partial\mathbb H^2$ such that each of the three hyperbolic lines $\overline{pq}$, $\overline{qr}$, $\overline{rp}$ are leaves of $\tilde\Lambda$. The ideal triangle with vertices $q,p,r$ is called a *Nielsen principal region* of $\tilde\Lambda$.

If there existed an orientation on $\Lambda$ then it would lift to an orientation on $\tilde\Lambda$, and so each of the three lines $\overline{pq}$, $\overline{qr}$, $\overline{rp}$ would be oriented. We may assume, by reversing the orientation if necessary, that $\overline{pq}$ is oriented from $p$ to $q$, and now we work our way around the triangle by continuity. Using that the lines $\overline{pq}$ and $\overline{qr}$ approach each other exponentially close in the direction of $q$, and projecting to $S$ and using a continuity and compactness argument, one proves that $\overline{qr}$ is oriented from $r$ to $q$. Continuing around the triangle in the same fashion, next one concludes that $\overline{rp}$ is oriented from $r$ to $p$, and then that $\overline{pq}$ is oriented from $q$ to $p$. But that's a contradiction because we started with $\overline{pq}$ being oriented from $p$ to $q$.